# I don't understand scaling in svglib

Tags: svg, png, reportlab

anyone knows in what consist scale in svglib ? whats the measure ? I don't get what correspond the 10 in this example, is it pixel, inch ... ?
Thank you for your help

```
drawing = svg2rlg(StringIO(textwrap.dedent('''
                {}'''.format(xml_svg))))
                # scale https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/207
                sx = sy = 10
                drawing.width, drawing.height = drawing.minWidth() * sx, drawing.height * sy
                drawing.scale(sx, sy)
```

Comment: I think it's percentage of original (the normal meaning of scale in a SVG transform) e.g 1.1 will scale it to 110% of original size.

Comment: See https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/207